# Change the "about" text of beta sites

Tags: bug, stackexchange-2.0, beta-phase, tour

> Public betas typically last from 60 to 90 days, although they can go on longer.

I think it's fair to say that `60 to 90 days` is not anywhere near representative. Can we have that changed into a value that reflects the average of the actual beta periods?

*Sidenote: [my favorite site](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) has been in beta for a **thousand days.***

Comment: Yeaaaaah, 6+ months would seem to be a generously low figure, if not 12+

Comment: The new /about page (currently being deployed, it hasn't hit all beta sites yet) doesn't mention the beta status any more. There is a section on beta in /faq but it doesn't have any such time interval. So I guess this request is now moot.